# React-Bootstrap-Table-Next Only One Row of Data in Table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to create a table for my website and for some reason it is only showing the first row of data.

This is how I am formatting the columns of the data:

```
const { items } = this.props.item;
// console.log({ items });

// react - bootstrap - table - next
const columns = [{
  dataField: 'team',
  text: 'Team',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(row.team)[rowIndex]                      
  )      
}, {
  dataField: 'current_Rank',
  text: 'Current Rank',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(row.current_Rank)[rowIndex]
  )      
}, {
  dataField: 'new_Rank',
  text: '321 Rank',
  sort: true,
  formatter: (cellContent, row, rowIndex) => (
    Object.values(row.new_Rank)[rowIndex]
  )
}];
```

This is how I am returning the table so that it renders the table:

```
return (
      <BootstrapTable 
        keyField="team"
        data={items}  
        columns={columns}
        striped
        hover />              
    )
  }
}
```

The data:
[Picture from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogAIX.png)

Live site: https://nhl-321-pointsystem.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your network response for `/api/items` API call, and found out that the data contains only one item. This being one of the reason you're seeing a single row when the table is rendered.

> Please note the, another reason for the issue is, `react-bootstrap-table-next` key
>   `data` accepts a single Array object. **And not array of single object**.

You should **re-arrange your data** so that key 'team' will be present for all items in the array. And rest of the column header values (e.g. current_Rank) are available for each like.

Something like a `reformat` function I created in the sandbox available [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/32vl4x4oj6).

**Plus point** - After you apply the `reformat` function, you won't need `formatter` for each column unlike your previous solution.

**Alternate but recommended solution** would be to send the formatted response from the API endpoint only, instead of re-parsing and creating new object to fit the needs of UI.

Sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/embed/32vl4x4oj6